# HSDPA Dongles on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to use a HSDPA device on virtual box. My intention is not sharing internet connection, But sending AT commands to the device.
OS : Windows XP

Comment: Does it connect to USB?

Comment: Yes Michael. it is connected via USB .

Comment: Then it should work, from what I experienced, almost all USB devices that don't require massive data streaming will work.